# Is it possible to run a framer.js project inside an UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, framerjs

I created a walktrough animation for my iOS application using framer.js and works great, very fluid and responsive. Is there any way to include this project inside an UIWebView properly, so i don't have to recreate these animations?

Looks like its working if i bypass the local file restrictions error, but everything is scaled up/cut off on my phone's screen. Weird, because the same project works fine if i view it using Safari.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the easy but this is the solution:

1. Convert the app.coffee file to regular javascript using http://js2.coffee for example
2. Copy the generated JS code into the framer/framer.init.js file, inside the loadProject() function
3. In the same file, inside the init() function, remove both showBrowserAlert() and showFileLoadingAlert() calls.
4. Done, now you can open your project on localhost, and the html file can be included in an UIWebView